# Attachments not working with email

Tags: emails

I am facing an issue with the D7 file attachment vi email.

```
function app_standard_app_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
   global $user;
   $profile = user_load($user->uid);

    // Functionality to validate and save the file.
    $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg gif png'));
    $file = file_save_upload('app_icon', $validators, variable_get('file_temporary_path', NULL), FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    if ($file) {
        $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
        $file = file_save($file);
    }

    /* START: Send mail Logic */
    $subject = 'New NHID Application Submission';
    $to = 'xxx@gmail.com'; // To mail id.
    $from = variable_get('site_mail', FALSE); // From mail id
    $msg = '<b>NHID Standard application details: </b><br/><br/>';

    $attachment = array();
    if($file){
        $file_content = file_get_contents('tmp/'.$file->filename);
        $attachments = array(
            'filecontent' => $file_content,
            'filename' => $file->filename,
            'filemime' => $file->filemime,
        );
    }

    $params = array(
        'subject' => $subject,
        'body' => check_markup($msg, 'full_html', '', FALSE),
        'attachment' => $attachment
    );

    // Send out the e-mail.
    if(drupal_mail('nhdp_register', 'nhid_standard', $to, language_default(), $params, $from, TRUE)){
        //  drupal_set_message("Mail send successfully ");
        $record = $form_state['values'];
        $record['submitted'] = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
        // To save the NHID Standard Application submissions to the database
        drupal_write_record('nhid_submissions', $record);
    } else {
        //  drupal_set_message("Sending Mail Failed");
    }
```

I receive an email with the above code and also the file uploaded on the tmp directory. But i am not able to get the uploaded file as an attachment.

I have verified all the settings and MIME is enabled. Please suggest if i am missing anything.

Comment: Well, an obvious problem is that you're setting values on the `$attachments` array (with an 's' at the end) but you're passing an empty `$attachment` array to `drupal_mail()` as part of `$param` ... Also, you don't mention what module you're using for the attachments - core Drupal does NOT support email attachments, so in order for this to work you need a contributed module like Mime Mail that has the ability to attach files. Different contributed modules have different requirements for how to specify attachments in `$param`, so a proper answer requires know which module you're using.